# Low effort solution for packaging/distributing a desktop application on Windows

Tags: windows, package-manager, installer

I'm in the unfortunate situation of having to package a desktop application for Windows, and I'm looking for the path of least resistance to get there. At the moment, I simply throw all my resources, dlls and executables in a directory and zip it.

Features that I need (or not):

- Application icon, start menu entry
- No file associations are required
- Update handling is optional
- Self extracting archives, installer generators, "Package managers" — any technology is fair game as long as it gets the job done

  - Global, per user and local ("portable") installs are equally fine
  - I don't mind having to create a developer account to push to a public repository. However, users must be able to access it without account (the Windows store is *out*)
  - I don't mind having to host my own repository, as long as it is as simple as having some Git URL or a simple HTTP file server.
- Since I'm cross compiling the application, the tool must work under Linux (Wine is fine though, if it's not too painful to install)

So basically I just want a tool that I give my bundled resources and it will create an installer that extracts them to some location and adds a start menu entry.

I know that there are plenty of solutions for this out there, but I can't tell which ones fit my needs and I don't have the resources to try things out.

As a reference, Xournal++ uses NSI and [their generator file](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/blob/master/windows-setup/xournalpp.nsi) has >300 lines, which would be too much for me.

---

Additional context about the application I'm packaging: It is written in Rust and uses Gtk. Therefore, no runtimes are required whatsoever. All dependencies and resources can simply be copied to a path relative to the .exe location

Comment: Inno Setup looks promising so far